# Binding events from angular directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am using this https://github.com/prajwalkman/angular-slider and I am trying to bind the slider events `onStart` and `onMove` that seem to be built in to the directive.

The HTML for the module is

```
<slider floor="0" ceiling="100" step="1" precision="1" ng-model="playhead" id="seekBar"></slider>
```

and I want to be able to use the events in my controller. I tried:

`seekBar.addEventListener('onMove', function(event){...});`

but didn't have any luck with that. Can anyone explain how I am supposed to use these events from my controller?

Comment: Where are you seeing that he provided a way to bind to those events?

Comment: why don't you use the ng-model value instead to binding to onMove event?

Comment: The version you linked there is clearly marked as deprecated. I would check this one out: [https://github.com/venturocket/angular-slider](https://github.com/venturocket/angular-slider). I don't see any documentation saying you can define custom event handlers for onMove or onStart on either page however.

Comment: Looks like you can see onMove in the (blech) CoffeeScript here: https://github.com/prajwalkman/angular-slider/search?q=onmove&ref=cmdform

Comment: @Nick I don't know if there is a way, that is why I am asking. I do see the events in the source of the directive though. Also, I tried getting that venturocket one working yesterday in IE9 and it was failing. I just tried again and it seems to be working now so I may change it up. I really want to avoid having to load the full jQuery library and it seems this one will work.

Comment: Yeah I'm seeing the event defined, but no way for you to get at it from outside the directive. As far as I know you won't be able to pass anything (including your event handler) to the directive unless it is defined in its scope object.

Comment: Which is fine, I just need to know how to define it so I can access it. I have no problem modifying the source, I just don't know how to go about doing that.

Comment: You could [`$emit`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$emit) your own event from inside of the directive's source and catch it in your controller

Comment: Ok I was misunderstanding the question. My mistake

Comment: @MarcKline, that did it. I just did a `scope.$emit('onMove');` and then a `$scope.$on('onMove', function(event){log($scope.playhead)});` and it shows me the value when I slide

Comment: Couldn't you just do `$scope.$watch('playhead', func...)` instead without modifying the directive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're willing to edit the directive's source, you can inject your own Angular $emit inside of its own internal onMove handler:

```
// emit 'onMove' up the scope chain
scope.$emit('move');
```

Then, assuming your controller's scope is the parent of the directive, you can just insert the following into the controller:

```
$scope.$on('move', function(){
  console.log("move fired");
});
```

[Plunker demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/8er10IQTGIn6M4qflOur?p=preview)

You might consider [debouncing](https://www.npmjs.org/package/angular-debounce) the event handling a bit to avoid excessive responses to the event - whether or not that's useful for you depends on what you're doing.